# sum of cubes using formula

Tags: python, sum

Given

```
\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}
```

I need to compute the left hand side. I should make a list of the first 1000 integer cubes and sum them. 
Then I should compute the right hand side and to the same. 
Also, I am supposed to compare the computational time for the above methods.

What I've done so far is:

```
import time 
start = time.clock()


list = []
for n in range(0,1001):
    list.append(n**3)
print(list)
print("List of the first 1000 integer cubes is:",list, "and their sum is:", sum(list))

stop = time.clock() 
print("Computation time: ",stop-start, "seconds.")

a=0
for n in range (0,1001):
    a=(int)(n*(n+1)/2)
print ("Sum of the first 1000 integer cubes is:",a*a)
```

First part for the left hand side works fine, but the problem is the right hand side. 
When I type n=4, I will get the same result for the both sides, but problem occurs when n is big, because I get that one side is bigger than the other, i.e. they are not same.

Also, can you help me create a list for the right hand side, I've tried doing something like this:

```
a=[]
for n in range (0,10):
    a.append(int)(n**2(n+1)**2/4)
```

But it doesn't work.

For the computational time, I think I am supposed to set one more timer for the right hand side, but then again I am not sure how to compare them.

Any advice is welcome,

Comment: What error are you getting? You should also use `int((n*(n+1))/2)**2)` It works fine for me.

Comment: "It does not seem to work" is not a sufficient problem description. Please describe how your code is failing; include the full traceback if you're getting an exception, or if you're just getting unexpected results, show the results you're getting and what you expect.

Comment: @CeliusStingher It says "can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

Comment: Running a copy-paste version of what you are showing us, executes correctly from my command line.

Comment: @glibdud I've just added that. 
I want to use formula based on mathematical induction to compute sum of cubes of first 100 integers.

Comment: Like Celius, the given code runs to completion for me without any errors.

Comment: @glibdud But when I try to compute the sum k**3 for k in range (0,100) and sum using formula, I don't get the same result. That  is weird.

Comment: Why don't you post that instead of the code that works. Open a new question with that code and the error, and maybe we can help you because the information the post contains is functional.

Comment: @CeliusStingher I've just edited my question, hopefully it looks better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think what you tried in a `for` loop is completely wrong. If you want to prove the formula "the hard way" (non-inductive way it is) - you need to simply sum cubes of `n` first integers and compare it against your formula - calculated one time (not summed `n` times).

So evaluate:

```py
n=100
s=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    s+=i**3
###range evaluates from 1 till n if you specify it till n+1
s_ind=(n**2)*((n+1)**2)/4

print(s==s_ind)
```

Otherwise if you are supposed to use induction - it's all on paper i.e. base condition `a_1=1^3=((1)*(2)^2)/4=1` and step condition i.e. `a_n-a_(n-1)=sum(i^3)[i=1,...,n]-sum(j^3)[i=1,...,n-1]=n^3` (and that it also holds assuming `a_n`=your formula here (which spoiler alert - it does ;) )

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my question, hopefully this time it makes more sense.

Comment: still - the above holds - you don't do your formula in loop - you just compute it once, for predefined ```n``` - then you compare the sum of cubes in ```for``` loop and compare the processing times